# Select only visible objects in QGIS

Tags: qgis

Is there possible to select only visible objects in QGIS without using query?

I have several points in dataset which I have visualized and also disable view some of them.
I need select only those which are visible. Is this possible in QGIS?

Comment: You should provide more details. As it is written now, it is difficult to say what exactly you need.

Answer (score 0):

If they're all in the same layer, then you can just select the layer and select the features with the regular selection tool. Is there some reason that's not possible?